# Unit testing router component with Jest / React -> snapshot failed

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, react-router, jestjs

I am currently working on a small application and am busy with the Jest unit tests. Here I am trying to work with shallow rendering. Unfortunately the snapshots don't match and I don't know why (I've only been working with React and Jest for a week).

tests/index.test.tsx

```
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import React from 'react';
import { AppRouter } from '..';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
test('App component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<AppRouter routes={[]} />);
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

routes/index.tsx

```
export const AppRouter = ({ history, routes }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Router basename={BASE_NAME} >
      <AppRoutes routes={routes} />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

index.tsx.snap (snapshot with toJson -> enzyme-to-json )

```
exports[`App component 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;

exports[`App component should match snapshot 1`] = `
ShallowWrapper {
  Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular],
  Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <AppRouter
    routes={Array []}
  />,
  Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): Object {
    "batchedUpdates": [Function],
    "getNode": [Function],
    "render": [Function],
    "simulateError": [Function],
    "simulateEvent": [Function],
    "unmount": [Function],
  },
  Symbol(enzyme.__node__): Object {
    "instance": null,
    "key": undefined,
    "nodeType": "class",
    "props": Object {
      "basename": "/view/project-setup/",
      "children": <AppRoutes
        routes={Array []}
      />,
    },
    ....
```

Jest fail message

```
 FAIL  routes/tests/index.tsx
  ● App component

    expect(received).toMatchSnapshot()

    Snapshot name: `App component 1`

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    - ShallowWrapper {}
    + <BrowserRouter
    +   basename=""
    + >
    +   <AppRoutes
    +     routes={Array []}
    +   />
    + </BrowserRouter>

       8 | test('App component', () => {
       9 |   const wrapper = shallow(<AppRouter routes={[]} />);
    > 10 |   expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
         |                           ^
      11 | });
      12 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/__tests__/index.tsx:10:27)

 › 1 snapshot failed.
```

Comment: snapshot works as following if you haven't yet had any snapshot, it will create for the first time as you run it. If you have created a snapshot, it will compare with the newly created one with the existing one. Assuming that if the first time you set up wrong, then you made some changes to make it right. Of course it will get failed in the next run.

Comment: Thnx! Just removed the snapshot and the test is passing :)